# Is it possible to load ZK 7 theme jar dynamicaly from custom location?

Tags: java, themes, zk

I have jar with ZK 7 theme. Instruction says that

> Using a anchive-based theme in a ZK Application is simple. Simply put
>   the theme jar file inside the WEB-INF/lib folder of your ZK
>   application. During the startup of your application, the new custom
>   theme would be automatically registered, and available to use.

But what if I need to register and set by default theme, that not placed in WEB-INF/lib?
Say, can I somehow register theme, that user can upload?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible [to register a theme](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/Theming_and_Styling/Understanding_the_Theming_Subsystem/Registering_your_Theme) as long it's on the classpath.
For user uploading, I think it's impossible.
**But there is a good reason why this is impossible.**
You allow a user, to send any jar to the classpath, and the application to load an run what's inside the jar.
If I have bad intentions, do you find it smart if I can add mine jar's to your application?

Comment: About user's downloads - it's only example to demonstrate, that the jar is not in server default classpath. In real world I need to make possible customers to use their own themes. Well, I think, I understand which way I need to move on. Thanks.